# How does Descartes make contact with the world?

Tags: descartes, skepticism, solipsism

Descartes' [*cogito*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum) allows him to deny extreme [sceptism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scepticism); but then how does he actually make contact with the world as opposed to saying - *I exist and the world is my (unconscious) invention* -, i.e. [solipsism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove the existence of the *res extensa*, the sensible world, Descartes uses an argument that we nowadays don't accept anymore. First, he proves God:

1. I have an idea of perfection
2. An idea of perfection has to come from something perfect
3. I am not perfect
4. Then there has to be something else perfect (=God)

Then he says: if all that information from the senses isn't correct, I'm *deceived*, so there must be some bad deceiver. However, since God is ultimately good, he wouldn't accept such a bad deceiver, therefore I cannot be deceived. Therefore, the information from the senses is correct, and the sensible world exist.

---

On a metaphilosophical level, you could say Descartes breaks his world down and then builds it up again in his meditations:

- Assume the sensible world doesn't exist

  - Assume God doesn't exist

    - Assume you don't even exist yourself
    - Cogito ergo sum: yes, I *do* exist
  - Proof of God (via the idea of perfection)
- Proof of the existence of the res extensa

All these proofs are a bit outdated and there are criticisms on them. Especially the proof of God (and thereby also the proof of the res extensa) isn't accepted. However, in his time that was probably all very clear. The real problem he had, was the [Mind-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_problem) (how can mind and body interact if they're separated?).

> <sup>The problem was famously addressed by René Descartes in the 17th century, resulting in Cartesian dualism, and by pre-Aristotelian philosophers, in Avicennian philosophy, and in earlier Asian traditions. A variety of approaches have been proposed. Most are either dualist or monist. Dualism maintains a rigid distinction between the realms of mind and matter. Monism maintains that there is only one kind of stuff, and that mind and matter are both aspects of it.</sup>

In [Cartesian dualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism_%28philosophy_of_mind%29), there is contact between mind and body in the '[homunculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus)' (Latin for 'little man', but also the Latin name for the epiphysis), a little part of the brain<sup>1</sup>. The body sends information from the senses to the mind. The mind 'processes' those signals and returns commandos to the body. The mind can also do something without getting information from the senses, i.e. when it just thinks, and it can command the body in that case as well.

In this image, you can see the body-part of a human: eyes give information to the epiphysis, the mind processes the information, and sends a command to the arm, which moves.

> [image]
>
> <sub>René Descartes's illustration of dualism. Inputs are passed on by the sensory organs to the epiphysis in the brain and from there to the immaterial spirit.</sub>

<sup>1: Why there? According to Descartes that is the only part of the body that does not exist as two identical halves and doesn't have an identical twin. For example, it can't be the eye, because you have two, and it can't be your nose, because it has two nostrils.</sup>

Comment: Descarte admiited two substances - mind & extension (or body here). I don't think that this is quite answering what I am asking.

Comment: @MoziburUllah you asked about how the mind could contact with the body, not?

Comment: Not quite. Descarte is positing that ha can't doubt his own existence. Good. Now what about the other objects of the world? Do they exists - or are they figments of hisimagination. Thats what I'm asking when I say how does he make contact with the objects of the world. That is objects existing independently. Your answer is Descarte answering another related question. How does his mental world actuate itself within the world, that is by his body.

Comment: @MoziburUllah ah-ha! So the question actually is "how does Descartes prove the existence of the res extensa"? I'll edit my answer for that. According to the votes here there might be some confusion caused by your question, perhaps you could rephrase it to make it more clear? :)

Comment: @MoziburUllah Sorry for the delay, I just added information. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, that is what I was looking for. He relies on God to make the world objective. That is create it. Which is exactly in line with his Christian faith - although of course expressed in rational terms.

Comment: Though, if he has to bring in God to make contact with the world, then why bother with the cogito to dispel skepticism? You may as well bring him in the beginning. But I suspect that this gives an opening for a purely rational explication which the phenomenologists & existentialists picked up and ran with.